# How to add a row to a 3D array Array Google App scripts

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have some data with three columns, (PO, SKU, Units).  I've sorted this array by SKU. The data looks like the image below

[image]

I'd like to add a blank row in between each set of SKUs to make it easier to read, and perhaps add totals in later. For example, after the last AL-STSTCHOPPER record, and before the first CE-12-SLOT-WOOD-WATCH-DARK record, there needs to be a gap.  I've tried using a for loop to do this, with no luck.  I think there's an easier way, but not sure what it could be.  Code I have for this is as follows:

```
 var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SheetName");
var orderLog = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("URL").getSheetByName("Order Details");

 var orderSort = orderLog.getRange(3, 1, orderLog.getLastRow(), 3).getValues().
 sort(function(r1,r2){
 var a = r1[1];
 var b = r2[1];

 if(a>b){
   return 1;
 }else if (a<b){
   return -1;}
   return 0;

   });

Logger.log(orderSort);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can add blank row with a loop:

```
function whitespace() {
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); // SpreadsheetApp.open...
      var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); //ss.getSheetByName('sheetName');
      
      var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
      
      sheet
      .getRange(1, 2, lastRow)
      .getValues()
      .reverse()
      .forEach(function(row, i, all){
        if(all.length > (i+1) && row[0] && all[i+1][0] && row[0] != all[i+1][0]) sheet.insertRowBefore(lastRow - i);
      });
    }
```

2. You can do it by reading and writing an array:

```
function whitespace2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var arr = [];
  
  sheet
  .getRange(1, 1, lastRow, 3)
  .getValues()
  .forEach(function(row, i, all){
    if(all.length > (i+1) && row[1] && all[i+1][1] && row[1] != all[i+1][1]) {
      arr.push(row);
      arr.push(['','','']);
    }
    else arr.push(row);
  });
  
  sheet
  .getRange(1, 1, arr.length, 3)
  .setValues(arr);
}
```